WebRTC: Is there a way to capture the output audio from another application (e.g., google meet, zoom)?
Web App to record both input and output audio from conversations.
For this app I'm using WebRTC media devices.
Scenario:

User opens the web app and starts recording.
User starts a conversation in another tool (e.g., Google Meet, Zoom, etc.).
The web app must record both input (microphone) and output (speakers) audio.

I've already managed to record the audio from the microphone, but capturing the output audio (from a bluetooth speaker) is the problem.
Any ideas?

Not much you can do with any APIs in the browser I imagine. The system would need to expose that audio as an input device, then you can access it via the browser APIs like a mic input. How to route audio like that to a virtual device depends on your OS and may require installing some 3rd party tools and virtual device drivers.
